# Amazon SNS Python Boto - How to create a message to be sent

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, debian, amazon-sns

I am getting my head around using SNS to send a message from one server to another. I want to create a message to send to the other server using Python and Boto so I was wondering if someone could look at this code designed to send the message "scraped":

```
import boto
sns = boto.connect_sns()

# Create Topic
t = sns.create_topic("scraped")
t
{u'CreateTopicResponse': {u'ResponseMetadata': {u'RequestId': u''}, u'CreateTopicResult': {u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:your-account-id:Test'}}}
```

Then on the other hand I want some code to check for this message on the second server, so I had something like this:

```
import boto
sns = boto.connect_sns()

# Read Topics
sns.get_all_topics()
{u'ListTopicsResponse': {u'ResponseMetadata': {u'RequestId': u''}, u'ListTopicsResult': {u'Topics': [{u'TopicArn': u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:your-account-id:Test'}], u'NextToken': None}}}
```

My first question is, have I got the right end of the stick? This is an entirely new concept to me and I'm having a hard time getting my head around it.

My second question is in order to check would I just run a cronjob on the python checking script every 5mins or so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My first question is, have I got the right end of the stick?

I don't think so.

Imagine that SNS is just a bulletin board. Say you've posted a piece of paper to this bulletin board that says *"Write your name on at the top of this paper if you want to sign up for piano lessons."*  This is the "topic."

You then add, *"Write your name on the reverse side of this paper if you're a piano teacher looking for students. Also make a note of how you want to be notified when we find a new student: email, text message, or carrier pigeon."* Teachers who add their name are creating a "subscription" to the topic.

When a student writes his name (publishes to the topic), every teacher is then simultaneously notified, via their preferred method, that there's been a new sign-up.  It's up to each teacher to decide what to do with this information.

The code snippets that you have above are doing the first half of this.  You're creating a topic and then viewing the topics.  For it to do anything, you have to publish a message to the topic.  I have some [example code on my blog](http://www.jamiebegin.com/python-error-logging-to-amazon-aws-sns/) where I'm using Python's `logging` module to publish log messages to an SNS topic.  That might give you a better understanding of a real-world use case.